# Is Firefox dev tools able to catch all the error?

Tags: javascript, firebug, firefox-developer-tools

Since Firebug was discontinued I had to started using the Dev Tools.

I was debugging a page, when I was clicking a button it was not firing the event. I realized a function was not defined, the JS file reference was missing, however, the Dev Tools did not tell me about it.

Trying my old still installed Firebug it threw something like "ReferenceError: foo function is not defined".

Do I need to enable any options more for Dev Tools? or isn't Dev Tools able to catch all the errors?

**UPDATE**

Test case

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
              function DoSomething(e){
                     e.preventDefault();
                     foo();
              }
 </script>

<a href="www.google.com" onclick="DoSomething(event)">Click me!</a>
```

Comment: I've noticed that Firefox dev tools often skip error messages triggered during AJAX callback events

Comment: Are you sure the `JS` error is enabled in `Console` tab? _there is `Net`, `CSS`, `JS`, `Security`, `Logging` and `Server` tabs/filters that can be set as ON/OFF_

Comment: Yes, I am. Other errors have come up but not this one. But the way, this foo function inside a JQuery click event.

Comment: @Jamo Can you please put your code here (or even testcase)? before that can your test your code in refreshed Firefox, or in brand new profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the "JS" filter is enabled within the *Console* panel.

If that doesn't help to see the error, you may try the new console frontend. In Firefox prior to version 55 this can be enabled by going to [`about:config`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config) and setting the preference `devtools.webconsole.new-frontend-enabled` to `true`. In that new UI ensure that the filters "Errors" and "Warnings" are enabled.

If you still can't see the error logged, it's probably a bug in the DevTools. In that case you should try whether you can reproduce the problem in a [new Firefox profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles). If you can also reproduce it in the new profile, you should [report the bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox&component=Developer%20Tools%3A%20Console) (if there isn't one already; [bug 755553](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=755553) seems to be related) and either profile a URL to a page where the error occurs or attach a reduced test case.

Comment: I tried with the new version 55 but the problem persists, then I tried with another profile and worked! So something is wrong with mine. Thanks!